# Packages() doesn't return <link rel="next"> tag

Tags: nuget, artifactory

Artifactory Enterprise 4.13.0 rev 40268
I use local nuget feed.

https://path_to_artifactory_feed/Packages()
return 80 entries and

> link rel="self" title="Packages" href="Packages"

There is more than 80 packages in this feed, and I expected

> link rel="next" href="https://path_to_artifactory_feed/Packages()?skip=80" />

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This seem as a known issue, as you can see here: 
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12311

This issue should be fixed in the upcoming releases of Artifactory.
You can vote and watch this Jira in order to get a notification once this issue is resolved.

Comment: It seems to be different issue. I wrote about Packages() method, and there isn't next link at all